# Using =IIF to calculate hours but I need to use more than one IIF and it keeps crashing

Tags: excel, vba, iif

I have been creating a time clock program and I need to calculate the hours. So far, its working great until I get to the `Overtime1`, `Overtime2` and `Overtime3` options.

After 40 hours, the OT1 should show the value of anything over 40 hours, but less than 50. OT2 should show the hours between 50 and 60 and so on. 
The `Fields.TotalHours` is what brings back the total hours.

For the Standard hours, I use

```
= IIF(Sum(Fields.TotalHours) > 40 ,40,Sum(Fields.TotalHours))
```

and this works fine. Now I need to calculate anything over 40:
I am using this

```
= IIF(Sum(Fields.TotalHours) > 50 ,10, Sum(Fields.TotalHours) - 40)
```

it somewhat works by putting in a value of 10 for anything over 50 hours, but it then puts a negative value for anything less than 50.
To fix that, I have tried the following, but it crashes the report:

```
=IIF(Sum(Fields.TotalHours) > 50, IIF(Sum(fields.TotalHours) < 60),(Sum(Fields.TotalHours) - 50,10))
```

Comment: Can I check the following: if the `TotalHours` is, say, 55 hours, you want an output that says `Overtime1 = 10` and `Overtime2 = 5`?

Comment: I'm a bit confused; you've tagged VBA, but `Sum` is not a standard VBA function. On the other hand, `IIF` is not a standard Excel function. Are these formulas in a worksheet cell, or in a VBA code module? If they are in VBA, where is the `Sum` function coming from?

Comment: I am sorry for tagging VBA, this was in error. I am writing this in a C# windows application

Comment: Yes Alex, and if the total hours were 63, there would be 40 hours REG, 10 hours OT1, 10 Hours OT2 and 3 hours OT3